# How to set the value of a textbox when it has focus

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox with a keydown handler. The handler detects if you press escape and if so it is meant to clear the textbox value. However, calling `tb.value = ""` normally works, unless the textbox has focus in which case it does nothing. I suspect I have to select the text and delete it, but how? This is in Firefox 12.

Comment: In fact, I absolutely didn't get what you ask. Please include your JavaScript in the question to make the question more clear.

Comment: In this snippet, it works for Firefox 12 too: http://jsfiddle.net/xyce5/

Comment: The javascript is tb.value = ""; If the textbox has focus it doesn't work. If it doesn't have focus it does work (ie sets the value)

Comment: It is a <input type="text"> control, not a textarea. In jsfiddle changing it to input type="text" does not work (ie it does not set the value on escape)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:-

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/qj5AN/1/)**

### HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="content" />
```

### JS:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (document.activeElement.nodeName == 'INPUT')
    {    
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {  // Enter
                alert('Enter Key Up');
            }   
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {  // Esc               
                    alert('Esc Key Up');
                    $('#content').val("");
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why keyup when dan uses a keydown handler? And you should warn him that you're using jQuery (I don't get why so many people take it for granted).